# What happens when you call a function with different arguments

Tags: python-2.7, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I am practising an old assignment that I never managed to understand. I understand and get the correct output until '3,  11'. After that comes a = f2(b, c). What I don't understand is, f2 is normally defined as f2(c,a). I tried changing all c to b and all a to c in f2, but when I get to the step b = f1(c) (which is now b = f1(b), and then replace all a in f1 with b, I don't get the correct output with show(a, b) in the f1 function. The output should be a = 10 and b = 6, but since I've replaced all the a's, there is not an a left. I have no clue what I should be doing at the a = f2(b, c) step. Could someone please explain the further steps in order to reach the last 3 correct outputs?

The assignment: (sorry for the bad spacing, I can't manage to paste it properly, it pastes as one whole long line)

```
a = 3
b = 4

def show (x, y):                                                                                 
    print ‘%d, %d’ % (x, y)

def f1 (a):
    global b
    a *= 2
    b += 1
    c = a + b
    show(a, b)    
    return c

def f2 (c, a):
    a += 3
    b = f1(c)
    show(c, b)
    c = a + b 
    return c


show(a, b)
c = f1(a)
show(a, c)
a = f2(b, c)
show(a, b)

What will be printed when this program is executed?
```

The desired output:
3, 4

6, 5

3, 11

10, 6

5, 16

30, 6

Comment: Keep in mind that the parameters `c` and `a` to `f2`  are different then the global variables `c` and `a`. [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Comment: How are they different? What values would c and a have in the a = f2(b,c) step?

Comment: Do you have to use python 2.7 by any means?

Comment: Yes, python 2.7 is required in my course. This is an old exam assignment. @cslotty